# Как узнать свойство у id?

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

```
<script>
if ($('#tabs:active:2')){
alert("TRUE")
}
</script>
```

Comment: Давайте так: напишите, что Дано, и что Требуется_Узнать.

Comment: @Iranda
Вы издеваетесь так редактировать заголовок? "Как через узнать свойство у id?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var tab = $('#tabs:active:2');
if (tab){
    alert(tab.attr('id'));
}
```